# No permite hacer el input al usuario

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
import discord #importamos para conectarnos con el bot
from discord.ext import commands #importamos los comandos
import datetime 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description="Search the same username in different data bases.", help_command=None)
#Search
@bot.command()
async def user(ctx):
 setuser = bot.wait_for(input())
 if setuser == await bot.wait_for(input()):
    try:
      pass
    except:
      response = """
      > ERROR! No username value...
      """
    embed = discord.Embed(title="T O O L", description=response)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

#Help
@bot.command()
async  def  help(ctx):
  description = """
  HELP:\n
  > !user: (Search an username in different data bases.)\n
  > Ex: !user: hacker\n

  Created by @oskarmdz\n
  
  """
  embed = discord.Embed(title="tool", description=description)
  #timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
  #color=discord.Color.red()
  #embed.set_footer(text="{} % Wait please...".format(ctx.author.name))
  embed.set_author(name="@yo"),


  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching))
    print('STATUS: OPERATIVE')

bot.run('mitoken')
```

Estoy intentando que se pueda introducir un usuario para guardarlo en una variable para utilizarlo pero, no consigo hacer esto, tampoco se dónde está el error. Estaría agradecido si pueden ayudarme. Decir que, STATUS:OPERATIVE, se imprime en la consola, no sé por qué. También decir que en la aplicación discord, imprime en pantalla tres veces:

> BOT  [('*')]who are you: !user:
> [20:01]  BOT  [('*')]who are you:
> !user: [20:01]  BOT  [('_')]who are you: !user:

Answer (score 1):

La función `input` bloquea la ejecución del código. Puedes utilizar bot.wait_for("message") para esperar a recibir un mensaje de un usuario en discord. Adicionalmente, le puedes añadir un timeout y un check, para que sea únicamente del usuario / canal que esperas y que el bot espere únicamente durante un tiempo (Y no infinitamente).

Además, te recomiendo que si estás intentando buscar un usuario de discord, utilices los [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#converters).

```
@bot.command()
async def user(ctx, setuser: discord.User):
    ...
```

También está desaconsejado crear el comando de *help* por tu cuenta. Puedes crear tu propia clase de HelpCommand y subclasearla con la de discord.py